# Prerequisites for Learning Regression

Tags: regression, references

I am doing self-study to learn Data Science (software developer by profession) and needed to read and understand [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) but this book requires Linear Regression as prerequisite. I [searched here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=book%20linear%20regression) and got good books for Linear Regression and I can order one by Draper and Smit from [Amazon India](https://www.amazon.in/dp/8126531738/?coliid=I1IMQ0TPG00NT4&colid=2756TE36VIR9O&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it). This is the only one which I can afford buying, rest all are imported and out of my budget.

I only know Algebra and some Calculus which I learned in last 2 months from MOOCs and Khan Academy and lot of search  but I got no background either in Probability or Statistics.  Can I got straight to learning Linear Regression from the book ?

**NOTE:** I am not looking to learn Statistics or Math and I do not want to learn any theory either.  I just want to understand Linear Regression so that I can do my Data Science work.

Comment: dataschool.io has a short and intuitive tutorial on Linear regression.

Comment: @Nishad .. cool, I will check it out

Comment: @Nishad your answer was really helpful. I did not know Dataschool had tutorial on Linear Regression too. Put your reply as a separate standalone answer than a comment and I will rate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use linear regression, it is important to have basic probability. It is also interesting to have notions on mathematical notation, such as the summation symbol as they are used to express some indexes from a linear regression.

Understandings of basic statistics and statistical inference are also interesting to have, but it is usually explained in books about linear regression. You might want to do [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/statistical-inference/).

I would say your background is good enough to start the study on the topic.

The most important is to study it patiently and understand what the results say. I suggest [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/regression-models/).

Comment: Ah... these courses feel so good :) .  I found one more like this, Statistical Thinking for Data Science and Analytics on [edX](https://www.edx.org/course/statistical-thinking-for-data-science-and-analytics) .  I will do all of them I guess